# Undefined symbol error during the compiling with ImageMagick library on Mac.

Tags: imagemagick, undefined, symbols

When I try to compile my simple code which is meant to resize a image file using ImageMagick library, I'm getting the following error.

```
$ gcc `pkg-config --libs --cflags ImageMagick` imagemagick_example.c

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_DestroyMagickWand", referenced from:
      _main in ccx4lMf2.o
  "_MagickGetImageHeight", referenced from:
      _main in ccx4lMf2.o
  "_MagickGetImageWidth", referenced from:
      _main in ccx4lMf2.o
  "_MagickReadImage", referenced from:
      _main in ccx4lMf2.o
  "_MagickResizeImage", referenced from:
      _main in ccx4lMf2.o
  "_MagickSetImageCompressionQuality", referenced from:
      _main in ccx4lMf2.o
  "_MagickWandGenesis", referenced from:
      _main in ccx4lMf2.o
  "_MagickWandTerminus", referenced from:
      _main in ccx4lMf2.o
  "_MagickWriteImage", referenced from:
      _main in ccx4lMf2.o
  "_NewMagickWand", referenced from:
      _main in ccx4lMf2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched for a way to fix this for an hour and couldn't find any works.
I'm using macOS 10.13.1 and home-brew installed ImageMagick 7.0.7-14.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MagickWand` for the C API.

```
gcc `pkg-config --libs --cflags MagickWand` imagemagick_example.c
```

Or skip `pkg-config` and use the helper utility that shipped with ImageMagick.

```
MagickWand-config --libs --cflags
```